# Do binding a same IntentService many times will create a queue of request?

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have a class `LocationProvider` extending `Service`. This LocationProvider class have a LocationListener inside that can detect a location coordinates and start an IntentService in order to provide a queue of process for sending the location coordinates to GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). I can start an IntentService by calling either `startService()` or `bindService()`. But I choose to use bindService(), because I like to anticipate a situation that when LocationProvider is destroyed, the IntentService and all of its queue will also stop. My question is, do binding a same IntentService many times can also make a queue? for that my request upon starting again an intentservice which where the sending of location to gcm is done one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With IntentService, All requests are handled on a single worker thread, but only one request will be processed at a time.

Hence, when many clients "bind" to IntentService, all those requests are handled on a single worker thread. So, worker thread may take as much time as it needed to process these requests in a Queue.

Of course, this being IntentService (and worker thread) mechanism it will not block the application's main loop, which is always desirable.

IntentService makes sure of automatic queuing of requests delivered to it, so if one request is being processed by the background thread, other commands queue up waiting their turn.

Comment: Thanks! I change my decision upon choosing between startService() or bindService(), I used startService for starting a IntentService. I added stopService() on my LocationProvider's onDestroy() method. so if ever that the LocationProvider destroyed it will immediately stop the IntentService and the queue on that worker thread. Again, thanks for this information! @ADDTechnical

Comment: Sure!! I guess most ofter IntentService is used with startService and app usually implements onHandleIntent.      automatic queuing of Intents delivered to onStartCommand(), so if one Intent is being processed by onHandleIntent() on the background thread, other commands queue up waiting their turn. And it IntentService automatically  shutdown once the queue is empty